# MYSQL Multiple join doesn't return all wanted rows re Employee-Supervisor-Item-Inspection

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

In my scenario employees inspect items (of some sort) periodically. I want to show an employee's name and the number of inspections they perform.

**Result from my query**

```
+------------------+------------------+
| employee         | inspections      |
+------------------+------------------+
| Peter Griffin    |              864 |
| Chris Griffin    |              655 |
| Meg Griffin      |              647 |
| Lois Griffin     |              457 |
| Stewie Griffin   |              332 |
+------------------+------------------+
```

My query sort of works, but I have a field called `active` in the table `item` which is supposed to exclude it from the `COUNT` (the item is not to be inspected). The `WHERE i.active = 1` doesn't have the correct effect. Items not active still get counted. And reversing the query to select **not** active items with `i.active = 0` shows a count of 7 when there are hundreds of items with `active = 0`. What am I doing wrong?

**My query**

```
SELECT concat(e.first_name,' ',e.last_name) AS employee, COUNT(insp.item_id) AS inspections
FROM employee e,
inspection_schedule insp,
item_supervisor super,
item i
WHERE i.active = 1
and e.employee_id = super.employee_id
AND super.item_id = i.item_id
AND insp.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY employee
ORDER BY inspections DESC
```

**Table overview**

[image: Table overview]

**Table explanation**

***ITEM:*** Items employees work with.

***ITEM_SUPERVISOR:*** Connects item to employee. More than one employee can be connected to one specific item.

***INSPECTION_SCHEDULE:*** An item to be inspected every other month will have 6 entries with the corresponding number of a month.

Comment: Would you mind adding little bit of data to help understand this better, please?

Comment: *"And reversing the query to select not active items with i.active = 0 shows a count of 7 when there are hundreds of items with active = 0."*
These items you are talking about may not have any supervisor or related inspection_schedule. You query condition excludes such records.

Comment: What is logical relationship between `item` and `inspection_scedule` tables? I can see from the schema it is at least `1 - *`. Is it actually `1 - 1` or `1 - 0..1`?.

Comment: Dhruv, In what format would you like the data in?

Comment: Ivan, relation between item and inspection_schedule is actually 1 - 0...1.
The relation between item and item_supervisor is 1 - * (however I see now I have a mismatch, 1629 rows/1639 rows. 10 items are dont have a item_supervisor)

Comment: Correction! 7 items do not have an entry in item_supervisor. So I guess this is where my result of 7 inspections comes from when I specify "i.active = 0". Although 509 items have 'active = 0' so it does not produce the desired result

Comment: You need to edit your question to include example input, output and desired output, because we don't know what result you want, we only know what query you wrote, and it's *wrong*. Your table descriptions are not helpful. You need to edit your question to make them of the form ITEM: "item *item_id* belonging to customer *customer_id* is at *location_id* and *active* = 1 is whether it is active". Only if you give such *predicates* can we tell when a row goes in a table. Then you need to edit your question to give a predicate for the rows you want from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current design can have an item scheduled without having a supervising employee and it can have a supervising employee without being scheduled. Your current query asks for data for active items that have a supervising employee and are scheduled.

You have to decide whether your design is correct, and if not, correct it. If you want all scheduled items to have supervising employees, its foreign key should reference Item_supervisor instead of Item. Then maybe your query is the one you want.

If your design is correct then you seem to not want that query. You have to decide what query you want. An item that doesn't have a supervising employee doesn't have a supervising employee name. If you want a result row per supervising employee then only the current query makes sense. If you want a result row per active inspection before you group, presumably you would have a group for items that have no supervising employee. You get that by starting your FROM with Inspection_schedule LEFT JOIN Item_supervisor ON item_id, which gives a NULL employee_id to unsupervised items. Then join with Item and Employee. You'll get all NULL employee_ids in one group.

PS Your table descriptions are not helpful for a user to update or query the database. You need them to be of the form ITEM: "item *item_id* belonging to customer *customer_id* is at *location_id* and *active* = 1 is whether it is active". Only if you give such a *predicate* per base table can we tell which rows of values actually belong in it. Or know what a row of values says about the application by being in a table (base or query result) or by not being in it. Then you need to decide on a predicate for the rows that you want to be in your query result.

Comment: First of all, thank you!

As you said, I want all scheduled items to have supervising employees. I corrected the foreign key and added a couple of missing rows in item_supervisor. The query functions perfectly now.

ITEM - ITEM_SCHEDULE is allowed to have 1...0..* relationship since some items will not demand inspection.

And the "Table explanation" above is not the description in the sql. Just something i quickly wrote down to be more precise. But with alot of thinking and too little sleep maybe I didn't make any sense.